# MySQL having issues displaying records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been working on a piece of code for a project that will show vehicle BOLO's (be on look out). The records for the Bolo's are stores in a table called bolos. When I return my case, it will echo "No Bolos On Vehicle", but if it finds a bolo, it will not display it nor will it display "No Bolos On Vehicle".

```
$q = strip_tags($_GET['q']);
$getVeh = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE vehicle_id='$q'";
$result = $pdo->prepare($getVeh);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    echo "<h6>Plate: " . $row['vehicle_plate'] . "</h6><br-leo-name-search>";
    echo "<h6>Color: " . $row['vehicle_color'] . "</h6><br-leo-name-search>";
    echo "<h6>Model: " . $row['vehicle_model'] . "</h6><br-leo-name-search>";
    echo "<h6>Insurance Status: " . $row['vehicle_is'] . "</h6><br-leo-name-search>";
    echo "<h6>Registration Status: " . $row['vehicle_rs'] . "</h6><br-leo-name-search>";
    echo "<h6>VIN: " . $row['vehicle_vin'] . "</h6><br-leo-name-search>";
    echo "<h6>Owner: " . $row['vehicle_ownername'] . "</h6><br-leo-name-search>";
    $plate = $row['vehicle_plate'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bolos WHERE vehicle_plate =:veh_plate");
    $stmt->bindParam(':veh_plate', $row['vehicle_plate']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $bolosRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($bolosRows['bolo_id']))
        {
        echo "<hr><h6>No Bolos On Vehicle</h6>";
        }
      else
        {
        $getVehBolo = "SELECT * FROM bolos WHERE vehicle_plate=:plate";
        $result = $pdo->prepare($getVehBolo);
        $stmt->bindValue(':plate', $plate);
        $result->execute();
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><center><font color='red'>" . $row['bolo_reason'] . "</font></center></td>";
            echo "<td><center><font color='red'>" . $row['bolo_created_on'] . "</font></center></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

        echo "</table>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is my database column design. http://prntscr.com/lygruj

Comment: Sounds like a good time to debug.  Observe the runtime values of your variables.  Are they always what you expect them to be?  When you execute your database queries, what are the exact results?

Comment: It's pulling all the correct information, as shown here http://prntscr.com/lygsnd

But if there are no records in the table that match, it does it correctly and echos "No Bolos On Vehicle" as seen here
http://prntscr.com/lygt3a

Comment: Which all suggests that something in that overall `else` block isn't doing what you expect it to do.  That's where the debugging comes in.  Maybe an error is silently occurring?  Maybe the parameter being used in the query or the results of the query aren't what you expect them to be?  If it's not displaying *anything* from that `else` block then that suggests there are no records to loop over.  You can even examine your resulting HTML to see if that lone errant `</table>` output is there.  (Also, why do you try to output `<table>` for every element in the loop?)

Comment: I completely forgot that I had the table in the loop, in which I fixed that. I have no error logs, and I have tried to debug, but still nothing.

Comment: In your `else` block you have `$result = $pdo->prepare($getVehBolo);` but then `$stmt->bindValue(':plate', $plate);`. In the second statement you should be using `$result` again

Comment: @Nick I attempted that, as shown here and still nothing. prntscr.com/lyh0xg

Comment: What else could I try to attempt to get this working?

Comment: You are also using two $row variable. It will conflict with the main while loop